# How do I get my cursor stuck in between monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse

So I got a new PC, but the old one had it so I had to force my cursor between monitors or it'd get stuck. I got me new PC and now it doesn't. I actually miss having to force my cursor through and was wondering how to turn it back on.

I have four monitors, but it did it with two before too. All four monitors are in a perfect sqaure but for some reason when I got my new pc it stopped.
I looked up all kinds of things, and messed with the display settings a lot, but nothing changed. Does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can acheive this:

1. Adjust the monitor position in Windows display settings(rectangles representing your monitors) so they are not exactly horizontally aligned; that way you will not be able to seamlessly move the cursor between them.
2. Install DisplayFusion; from there you can assign a shortcut to lock/unlock the mouse on specific monitor AND/OR move between them.